# start a program from cmd with full permission

Tags: php, windows, cmd, permissions, exec

i have an application called app.exe it's create a file called account.txt in the same folder c:\ , the problem is that when i run the program from php exec function or cmd the account.txt file is not creating 
i think the problem is from the permissions.

Run From:         What happened

Manualy            Executed and created the file account.txt

PHP exec         Executed but it did't create account.txt

CMD                 Executed but it did't create account.txt

for php i use:

```
exec("C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c START c:\app.exe");
```

for cmd i use:

```
START C:\app.exe
```

Comment: Does it ask for elevation (UAC) when you run "manually"?

Comment: No it doesn't ask for permission

Answer (score 1):

A program that requires elevation should specify so in its [manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx). This would not help with the PHP issue though, especially if this is a web server using PHP. It is not possible to elevate without showing the UAC UI.

I'm not aware of a simple way to request elevation when executing something in Cmd. You might just have to start Cmd elevated (Right-click and "Run as Administrator").

PHP might be running as a different user but you gave us zero information about your setup so I don't know.

Without knowing anything about app.exe nor your Windows version or general configuration it is hard to give specific advise.

If you want to confirm that it as a permissions problem you can try running [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) so you can see why the file operation fails.

Comment: Im running windows 7 ultimate with appserv 2.5.10

Comment: note that if i click on it manualy with mouse the txt file is created successfully the problem that is when i run it from cmd or from exec function in PHP

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the runas command

```
runas /profile /user:*admin user here* “*path to program here*”
```

you will then be prompted for that users password and after that it should run as admin.

Comment: This does not elevate!